# What are the requirements for the Mousetrap Maibock recipe?

Tags: fiz

I've completed my New Game Plus in Fiz, but I haven't seen the Mousetrap Maibock become available yet. I think I remember buying it in my first game...

I have 59 recipes now, and I'm waiting for this one before I start my next New Game Plus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Mousetrap Maibock isn't purchased; you get it by tapping on a mouse.

Comment: I think it maybe more than just that.  It might require a number of mouses in a row without missing one.  I could be wrong though.

Comment: @spartacus I just got it after missing a mouse before it. Maybe it's a semi rare drop that only occurs after some point?